# How to view other users' objects like mine in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbobject

When I access other users' objects, I can do something like

```
select * from user_2.booking_table;
```

given that I have the privileges over `user_2`'s objects.

Using the console, I know I can do

```
alter session set current_schema=user_2;
```

to avoid prefixing `user_2` in front of object's name - so I can do

```
select * from booking_table;
```

as if `booking_table` is my table without specifying `user_2` each time.

---

*If I want to bring similar idea to GUI client...*

Using Oracle SQL Developer, under each connection, I know I can browse other users' objects under the tree node `Other Users` > `user_2` > `Tables`/`Views`/`Indexes` etc...

Is there anyway I can *"import"* `user_2`'s objects so that they appear under my `Tables`, `Views`, `Indexes`, etc under the connection, as if they look like they are my objects?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: If it were possible, what would you expect to appear or happen if both schemas had a table with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. We show you what you have, or what other schemas have.

The only way to get close to what you're looking for is if you were to create synonyms to tables in other schemas, then you can ask SQL Developer to present those as TABLES in your connection list.

I'm logged in as a user with an 'empty' schema, at least as far as tables are concenred.

[image]

I enable this filter check item, and click 'OK' -

[image]

[I talk about this in detail here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/03/why-cant-i-see-my-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer/)

*Disclaimer: I'm the product manager for Oracle SQL Developer.*